# Can we make the url to launch in new window in flutter?

Tags: url, flutter, dart

I am using url_launcher for being redirected to the login web page for my flutter app. Is there any attribute which can make it "open in new window"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to wrap this login page in WebView? and open this Login WebView Widget?

Comment: wrap the login  page to web view, if that means I want to redirect my app to a web page (just as we use for payment gateway) and come back